# Divide too long text in similar chunks considering punctuation

Tags: python, chunks, maxlength, punctuation, sentence

I have a list of strings that **have to be not more than X characters**. Each string *can contain many sentences (separated by punctuation like dots)*. I need to separate longer sentences than X characters with this logic:

I have to divide them into the **minimum number of parts** (starting from 2), in order to have all the chunks **with a lower length than X as similar as possible (possibly identical)**, but **considering the punctuation** (example: if I have `Hello. How are you?`, I can't divide it into `Hello. Ho` and `w are you?` but in `Hello.` and `How are you?` because it's the most similar way to divide it into two equal parts, without loosing the sense of the sentences)

```py
max = 10
strings = ["Hello. How are you? I'm fine", "other string containg dots", "another string containg dots"]
for string in string:
   if len(string) > max:
       #algorithm to chunck it
```

In this case, I will have to divide the first string `Hello. How are you? I'm fine` into 3 parts because with 2 parts, I'll have one of the 2 chunks longer than 10 characters (max).

Is there a smart existing solution? Or does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: maybe the https://www.nltk.org/ could help you in that, other than that, you can start by making a function for chopping your giving string at certain punctuation marks and see if you can accommodate within the size restriction and return a list or something as result

Answer (score 1):

An example function for chunking string (within the character minimum and maximum lengths) by punctuation (e.g. ".", ",", ";", "?"); in other words, prioritizing punctuation over character length:

```
import numpy as np
def chunkingStringFunction(strings, charactersDefiningChunking = [".", ",", ";", "?"], numberOfMaximumCharactersPerChunk = None, numberOfMinimumCharactersPerChunk = None, **kwargs):
  if numberOfMaximumCharactersPerChunk is None:
    numberOfMaximumCharactersPerChunk = 100
  if numberOfMinimumCharactersPerChunk is None:
    numberOfMinimumCharactersPerChunk = 2
  storingChunksOfString = []
  for string in strings:
    chunkingStartingAtThisIndex = 0
    indexingCharactersInStrings = 0
    while indexingCharactersInStrings < len(string) - 1:
      indexingCharactersInStrings += 1
      currentChunk = string[chunkingStartingAtThisIndex:indexingCharactersInStrings + 1]
      if len(currentChunk) >= numberOfMinimumCharactersPerChunk and len(currentChunk) <= numberOfMaximumCharactersPerChunk:
        indexesForStops = []
        for indexingCharacterDefiningChunking in range(len(charactersDefiningChunking)):
          indexesForStops.append(currentChunk.find(charactersDefiningChunking[indexingCharacterDefiningChunking]) + chunkingStartingAtThisIndex)
        indexesForStops = np.max(indexesForStops, axis = None)
        addChunk = string[chunkingStartingAtThisIndex:indexesForStops + 1]
        if len(addChunk) > 1 and addChunk != " ":
          storingChunksOfString.append(addChunk)
          chunkingStartingAtThisIndex = indexesForStops + 1
          indexingCharactersInStrings = chunkingStartingAtThisIndex
  return storingChunksOfString
```

Alternatively, to prioritize character length; as in, if we want to consider our (average) character length and from there, find out where our defined characters for chunking are:

```
import numpy as np
def chunkingStringFunction(strings, charactersDefiningChunking = [".", ",", ";", "?"], averageNumberOfCharactersPerChunk = None, **kwargs):
  if averageNumberOfCharactersPerChunk is None:
    averageNumberOfCharactersPerChunk = 10
  storingChunksOfString = []
  for string in strings:
    lastIndexChunked = 0
    for indexingCharactersInString in range(1, len(string), 1):
      chunkStopsAtADefinedCharacter = False
      if indexingCharactersInString - lastIndexChunked == averageNumberOfCharactersPerChunk:
        indexingNumberOfCharactersAwayFromAverageChunk = 1
        while chunkStopsAtADefinedCharacter == False:
          indexingNumberOfCharactersAwayFromAverageChunk += 1
          for thisCharacter in charactersDefiningChunking:
            findingAChunkCharacter = string[indexingCharactersInString - indexingNumberOfCharactersAwayFromAverageChunk:indexingCharactersInString + (indexingNumberOfCharactersAwayFromAverageChunk + 1)].find(thisCharacter)
            if findingAChunkCharacter > -1 and len(string[lastIndexChunked:indexingCharactersInString - indexingNumberOfCharactersAwayFromAverageChunk + findingAChunkCharacter + 1]) != 0:
              storingChunksOfString.append(string[lastIndexChunked:indexingCharactersInString - indexingNumberOfCharactersAwayFromAverageChunk + findingAChunkCharacter + 1])
              lastIndexChunked = indexingCharactersInString - indexingNumberOfCharactersAwayFromAverageChunk + findingAChunkCharacter + 1
              chunkStopsAtADefinedCharacter = True
      elif indexingCharactersInString == len(string) - 1 and lastIndexChunked != len(string) - 1 and len(string[lastIndexChunked:indexingCharactersInString + 1]) != 0:
        storingChunksOfString.append(string[lastIndexChunked:indexingCharactersInString + 1])
  return storingChunksOfString
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried both the two methods. The average-based function works well even if for my purpose it would be better to use the max-based function (the first you put). Unfortunately with that method, the slices that come out to me are long exactly 1 sentence (from a dot to other dot), so maybe there is something to change, but it is a good starting point!